# Serial connection to radio using WINE

Tags: usb, serial-port, minicom

I can run the software for my CRT SS 9900 radio using the mfrs serial-to-USB cable under WINE on Zorin/Ubuntu. However, I cannot connect on any of the COM ports.

I have set `/ttyUSB0` using `minicom` but I don't understand how this corresponds with the available serial ports listed in the software: **COM1** to **COM33**. None of the low numbers allow me to communicate with the radio.

What am I missing?

Comment: Why you do not use USB (which is available on the back of this radio)?

Comment: That is what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

According to [4.3.1 Serial and Parallel Ports](https://wiki.winehq.org/Wine_User%27s_Guide#Serial_and_Parallel_Ports) on WineHQ's Wiki:

> To override Wine's default device mapping, run wine regedit and create
>   string entries in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Wine\Ports` where the
>   entry name is the Windows device name and the entry value is the path
>   to the Unix device. Continuing with the above example, to make `COM1`
>   the first USB-attached serial port, create an entry with the name `COM1`
>   and the value `/dev/ttyUSB0`.

So you could just add an entry for `COM1` as documented above.

Check also permissions and groups (`dialout`?) assigned to `/dev/ttyUSB0`. The user running wine needs of course to have read/write access, usually by adding it to `dialout` and logging again.

Comment: Thanks - although I only understand about half of your instructions.

Comment: What don't you understand, more specifically?

Comment: "where the entry name is the Windows device name and the entry value is the path to the Unix device"

Comment: No idea how to "Check also permissions and groups (dialout?) assigned to /dev/ttyUSB0. The user running wine needs of course to have read/write access, usually by adding it to dialout and logging again."

Comment: Let's tackle last part first: the serial port has access restriction. being part of the dialout group allows to use it. If you configure the port as "root" and run wine (or anything else) as "someuser" and "someuser" doesn't belong to the "dialout" group, then "someuser" can't access the serial port. this dialout is for Debian systems. Anyway it's just access right you can read with `ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0` to figure out if there's a specific group etc. Got this part?

Comment: ls: cannot access '/dev/ttyUSB0': No such file or directory

Comment: You wrote in your question: "I have set `/ttyUSB0` using minicom but". Get your facts straight. It has to be `/dev/` before. if it's not `ttyUSB0` only you can know what it is, not me.